# AWK: get random lines of file satisfying a condition?

Tags: awk

I am trying to get a set number of random lines that satisfy a condition.

e.g. if my file was:

```
a    1    5
b    4    12
c    2    3
e    6    14
f    7    52
g    1    8
```

then I would like exactly two random lines where the difference between column 3 and column 2 is greater than 3 but less than 10 (e.g. lines starting with a, b, e, and g would qualify)

How would I approach this?

`awk (if something and random) '{print $1,$2,$3}'`

Answer (score 11):

You can do this in `awk` but getting the random selection of lines will be complex and will require writing quite a bit of code. I would instead use `awk` to get the lines that match your criteria and then use the standard tool `shuf` to choose a random selection:

```
$ awk '$3-$2>3 && $3-$2 < 10' file | shuf -n2
g    1    8
a    1    5
```

If you run this a few times, you'll see you get a random selection of lines:

```
$ for i in {1..5}; do awk '$3-$2>3 && $3-$2 < 10' file | shuf -n2; echo "--";  done
g    1    8
e    6    14
--
g    1    8
e    6    14
--
b    4    12
g    1    8
--
b    4    12
e    6    14
--
e    6    14
b    4    12
--
```

The `shuf` tool is part of the GNU coreutils, so it should be installed by default on most any Linux system and easily available for most any *nix.

Comment: Selecting a single value is easy (`condition && rand() < 1 / ++n { selection = $0 }`), but I'm not sure how to adapt that to selecting N, so yeah, `shuf` is probably the way to go.

Comment: @Kevin ah, clever trick with the `/ ++n`! However, the problem is that i) you need to also use `srand()` to set a random seed else you always get the same output and ii) you can sometimes get no output at all for a small file. I tried extending it to print two lines, but I still can't get past ii): `awk 'BEGIN{srand()}{if($3-$2>3 && $3-$2 <10 && rand() < 1 / ++n){a[k++]=$0}if(k>1){print a[0]"\n"a[1]; exit}}' file` and, in any case, that's more effort than it's worth, as you said.

Comment: I believe `awk -v count=2 'BEGIN { srand() } $3 - $2 > 3 && $3 - $2 < 10 && rand() < count / ++n { if (n <= count) { s[n] = $0 } else { s[int(rand()*count)] = $0 } } END { for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) print s[i] }' file` should work... but I'm not a statistician.

Comment: @Kevin looks like it. Nice one! May as well make it into an answer. If only to show why we tend to use existing utilities when possible :)

Comment: sure, done. I did notice a bug in the comment, fixed in my answer.

Comment: where does one get `shuf`

Comment: @Kevin You may be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling

Comment: @SumNeuron on what operating system?

Comment: @terdon Im using MacOS

Comment: @SumNeuron ah. Next time, please remember to mention that in your question. It makes a *huge* difference since the default versions of the tools you get on MacOS, UNIX and Linux can be very different. Anyway, to install the GNU tools on a mac, see [1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69332/112433) or [2](https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/) (those were just the first hits for "gnu coreutils macos", I'm sure you can find others).

Answer (score 5):

If you want a pure awk answer that only iterates through the list once:

```
awk -v count=2 'BEGIN { srand() } $3 - $2 > 3 && $3 - $2 < 10 && rand() < count / ++n { if (n <= count) { s[n] = $0 } else { s[1+int(rand()*count)] = $0 } } END { for (i in s) print s[i] }' input.txt
```

Stored in a file for easier reading:

```
BEGIN { srand() }
$3 - $2 > 3 &&
$3 - $2 < 10 &&
rand() < count / ++n {
    if (n <= count) {
        s[n] = $0 
    } else { 
        s[1+int(rand()*count)] = $0 
    } 
} 
END { 
    for (i in s) print s[i] 
}
```

The algorithm is a slight variation on [Knuth's algorithm R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling#Algorithm_R); I'm pretty sure the change doesn't alter the distribution but I'm not a statistician so I can't guarantee it.

Commented for those less familiar with awk:

```
# Before the first line is read...
BEGIN { 
    # ...seed the random number generator.
    srand() 
}

# For each line:
# if the difference between the second and third columns is between 3 and 10 (exclusive)...
$3 - $2 > 3 &&
$3 - $2 < 10 &&
# ... with a probability of (total rows to select) / (total matching rows so far) ...
rand() < count / ++n {
    # ... If we haven't reached the number of rows we need, just add it to our list
    if (n <= count) {
        s[n] = $0 
    } else {
        # otherwise, replace a random entry in our list with the current line.
        s[1+int(rand()*count)] = $0 
    } 
} 

# After all lines have been processed...
END { 
    # Print all lines in our list.
    for (i in s) print s[i] 
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain this witchcraft for those uninitiated in `awk` :)

Comment: Added some explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it in GNU awk (which supports custom sort routines):

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

function mycmp(ia, va, ib, vb) {
  return rand() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1;
}

BEGIN {
  srand();
}

$3 - $2 > 3 && $3 - $2 < 10 {
  a[NR]=$0;
} 

END {
  asort(a, b, "mycmp");
  for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) print b[i];
}
```

Testing with the given data:

```
$ for i in {1..6}; do printf 'Try %d:\n' $i; ../randsel.awk file; sleep 2; done
Try 1:
g    1    8
e    6    14
Try 2:
a    1    5
b    4    12
Try 3:
b    4    12
a    1    5
Try 4:
e    6    14
a    1    5
Try 5:
b    4    12
a    1    5
Try 6:
e    6    14
b    4    12
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting a `perl` solution, as I don't see any reason why it must be in `awk` (except for the OP's wish):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my $N = 2;
my $k;
my @r;

while(<>) {
    my @line = split(/\s+/);
    if ($line[2] - $line[1] > 3 && $line[2] - $line[1] < 10) {
        if(++$k <= $N) {
            push @r, $_;
        } elsif(rand(1) <= ($N/$k)) {
            $r[rand(@r)] = $_;
        }
    }
}

print @r;
```

This is a classic example of [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling). The algorithm was copied from [here](https://webkist.wordpress.com/2008/10/01/reservoir-sampling-in-perl/) and modified by me to meet OP's specific wishes.

When saved in file `reservoir.pl` you run it with `./reservoir.pl file1 file2 file3` or `cat file1 file2 file3 | ./reservoir.pl`.